# When I open a specific animation the character shrinks and turns sideways

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms

Whenever I reopen the .blend file sometimes some of the animations will break and when I load them in the dope sheet or action editor, the skeleton rotates 90 degrees on all axes and shrinks down too.
Animations play just fine while its like that but when I try to rest the rotation and scaling <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> doesn't fix anything. But apparently When it is exported as an fbx then sent over to unity there aren't any problems.
Is there a way to fix this or just keep it from happening in the future?

Error:
[image: Shrinking]

How is should look:
[image: before opening the animation]

Comment: Maybe you have keyframes set on the armature object as well as on the armature bones? Maybe resetting transformations on the object would fix it.